# Laravel Secure Storage Route

Tags: laravel, authentication, storage

I am using the Storage::url() function for generating download links for files inside the storage directory, i also linked the storage directory to the public directory and everything is working fine.

However now any person can download the files without needing any authentication. What is the proper way to secure all routes starting with /storage/..... without having to re-write the download logic inside my controller?

Answer (score 0):

you must add the download URL as a route on your routes.php file :

```php
Route::get('downloads/{file}','MyController@download')->where('file', '^[^/]+$')->middleware('auth');
```

of course, don't forget to check if the file exists, after that you can use

```php
 $reponse()->download()
```

to return a download response. the method takes 3 parameters : file path, file name and HTTP response headers.

for more details, check this :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads